# What does raising voltage do?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, potential, voltage

If I raise the voltage of a wire from 0V to 1000V and then to 5000V, am I merely packing it with more and more electrons (with those electrons being trapped there until they find a path off the wire)?

Comment: Can you describe the physical situation a little more? There's one wire? Two? By what means are you increasing the potential difference?

Comment: Let's say it is an open circuit wire (nothing drawing any current) on the high side of a DC generator.

Comment: Can you add that to your question? Not everyone reads these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are increasing the number of electrons in the wire, but only by a very small amount.

There's a somewhat clichéd but still excellent analogy for electrical circuits called the [hydraulic analogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy). In the hydraulic analogy the power supply is a pump, and the pressure is the voltage. The water represents the electrons, so the pressure generated by the pump pushes water around the circuit just as the potential difference generated by a power supply pushes electrons around the wires.

Your open circuit is like having a pipe connected to the pump, but with the end of the pipe sealed off. When you raise the pump pressure you still can't pump any water because if the end of the pipe is sealed there's nowhere for the water to go.

Only this isn't quite true. Firstly water is slightly compressible, and secondly the walls of the pipe are slightly elastic. This means that as you increase the pump pressure you do push a very small amount of extra water into the pipe. An analgous effect happens in electric circuits as well, where the phenomenon is called [capacitance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance). If the capacitance of an object is $C$ and you apply a voltage $V$ then the extra charge on that object is given by:

$$ Q = CV $$

I can't find any equations for the capacitance of a piece of wire, but the capacitance of a sphere of radius $r$ is:

$$ C_{sphere} = 4\pi\epsilon_0 r $$

and therefore the charge is:

$$ Q = 4\pi\epsilon_0 rV  $$

So if you connected the end of your wire to a metal sphere the size of a tennis ball ($r = 0.034$ m) and ramped the voltage up to $5000$V the extra charge would be:

$$ Q = 1.89 \times 10^{-8} \text{C} $$

which is about $10^{11}$ extra electrons.

Comment: It may be worth noting that $10^{11}$ electrons looks like a lot but there are about $6\times10^{18}$ electrons-worth of charge in 1 coulomb, so those $10^{11}$ electrons ($1.7 \times 10^{-8}$ Coulombs) could only drive a 10mA LED for a microsecond or so. (or something - my arithmetic is pretty sloppy).

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is potential difference.  A higher voltage means that there is more energy that can be used from the same amount of current.  In effect, increasing the voltage is roughly analogous to adding more potential energy per electron, as opposed to current, which is moving more electrons through the wire.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The voltage is the chemical potential of photons instead to relating to electrons, in other words, an electromagnetic field is established across the wire which moves the electrons.

Back to your question, the number of electrons does not change in the wire at the open-circuit scenario, aka the electrons in the wire can't flow into or from anywhere.